# Python ValueError: Both dates must have the same UTC offset with .loc

Tags: python, pandas, valueerror

I am having trouble using loc to get all entries in a pandas DataFrame between two periods. For example, the two lines below both give me a value:

```
periods.loc[start]

periods.loc[end]
```

However, when i run the following, I get a ValueError: "Both dates must have the same UTC offset":

```
periods.loc[start:end]
```

I was expecting to get a DataFrame with all of the entries that fall between those two dates. All of the entries are a string in the form of "yyyy-mm-dd".
Here are the first 10 entries of periods:

```
0    2007-01-25 09:10:02
1    2007-01-26 07:03:01
2    2007-02-02 04:50:51
3    2007-02-06 07:54:35
4    2007-02-07 06:31:05
5    2007-02-07 09:09:47
6    2007-02-07 09:43:12
7    2007-02-09 07:34:55
8    2007-02-13 04:32:04
9    2007-02-15 06:30:51
```

Comment: Could you give a sample of the values inside `periods`??

Comment: Sure. An example that throws an error is when start='2007-02-21 06:43:09' and end='2007-03-19 08:53:51'

Comment: What is the value of `periods`? Could you print the first 10 data points and post it to your code?

Comment: sure. just made an edit to the OP. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert your data into `datetime.datetime` objects. Here is a complete example of how you can do that:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from datetime import datetime


>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"date": ["2007-01-25 09:10:02", "2007-01-26 07:03:01",
...                             "2007-02-02 04:50:51", "2007-02-06 07:54:35",
...                             "2007-02-07 06:31:05", "2007-02-07 09:09:47",
...                             "2007-02-07 09:43:12", "2007-02-09 07:34:55",
    ...                         "2007-02-13 04:32:04", "2007-02-15 06:30:51"]})
>>> # convert the date column to datetime object
>>> df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
>>> df
                 date
0 2007-01-25 09:10:02
1 2007-01-26 07:03:01
2 2007-02-02 04:50:51
3 2007-02-06 07:54:35
4 2007-02-07 06:31:05
5 2007-02-07 09:09:47
6 2007-02-07 09:43:12
7 2007-02-09 07:34:55
8 2007-02-13 04:32:04
9 2007-02-15 06:30:51
```

Now, let's slice it using `start` and `end` which are both dates:

```
>>> start = "2007-01-25 09:10:02"
>>> end = "2007-02-07 08:53:51"

>>> # convert start and end from string to datetime object
>>> start = datetime.strptime(start, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
>>> end = datetime.strptime(end, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

>>> # let's access some values
>>> df.loc[(df["date"] >= start) & (df["date"] < end)] #mimics the slice object
                 date
0 2007-01-25 09:10:02
1 2007-01-26 07:03:01
2 2007-02-02 04:50:51
3 2007-02-06 07:54:35
4 2007-02-07 06:31:05
```

Also, you can access any particular date using `loc`:

```
>>> new_date = "2007-02-07 06:31:05"
>>> new_date = datetime.strptime(new_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
>>> df.loc[df["date"] == new_date]
                 date
4 2007-02-07 06:31:05
```

Comment: Worked. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could  help :)